# Why Postman response differs from unit test response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I have an issue with different response bodies after making the same requests, but in different scenarios.

**Scenario #1:** Unit test.

```
/**
* {@code GET /api/entity/{id}} - check acquiring of non-existing entity (id not found).
*/
@Test
public void getEntityNotExistingTest() throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<String> getResponse = restTemplate
            .getForEntity("/api/entity/9999", String.class);
    System.out.println(getResponse.getBody());
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-06-23T18:34:13.488+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/entity/9999"
}
```

**Scenario #2:** Postman.
Request: `GET localhost:8080/api/entity/9999`.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-06-23T18:36:25.277+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Unable to find entity of 9999 id",
    "path": "/api/entity/9999"
}
```

The `message` is missing in the 1st response. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this. I added the `server.error.include-message` property to my overriden `application.properties` file in `test` directory . I set its value to `always`.

I'm still unsure why did I have to do that, because in my `src`'s `application.properties` I didn't explicitly mention this property.